# Uses same PM2 processes for all users(also root)

Tags: permissions, pm2

I have pm2 installed by default from the root user in `/root/.pm2`, and i've used without problems.

Nex that i had to add two users (with their dir in `/home/dir1 and /dir2`.

But when i enter with one of that user, and i use pm2 list or pm2 start, it seems it uses the .pm2 installed in the users dir. SO how can i make that all other users, uses the same default .pm2 istance/folder? 
(they already have the permissions to access that folder).

Thank you!